# Add Scroll EventListener to Document in GatsbyJS (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How should I add the following eventlistener to a GatsbyJS (ReactJS) functional component?

**EventListener**

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', _ => document.getElementById('logo').style.setProperty('--v-adjust', window.scrollY + 'px'))
```

**Functional Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

export default () => {
    //graphql statement
    return (
        <>...</>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed the *useEffect* hook to perform the action.
[Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

**Updated Component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

export default () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', _ => document.getElementById('logo').style.setProperty('--v-adjust', window.scrollY + 'px'))
    })
    return (
        <>...</>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, I ran into the same issue and I noticed an additional event listener was being added after each Gatsby navigation. Normally the browser will remove those event listeners but due to Gatsby's "soft" navigation we need to do this manually

Comment: Additionally if you wanna go a step further use [passive event listeners](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md#feature-detection) for better scrolling performance